# Converting garage into living room?

Tags: garage, foundation, waterproofing, renovation, concrete-block

We want to convert the garage into the living room. Our house has a crawl space under it. But the garage is a slab with cinder blocks around it. Water comes in through the garage door when it rains enough. Not sure if we just block the door entrance and fill it in with concrete if it will be enough to keep the water out? We will also be placing a man door there. But it will be on top of the cinder blocks. Or is there another way we should do this? We are also thinking about putting a drain system in front of where the door was to help.

Comment: Fix the water problem before you invest in remodeling. Is the issue your driveway slopes towards the garage? If so, regrade the driveway or install perimeter drains.

Comment: Ya it slopes toward it. He putting in some drain system that will go underground in front of the door.

Comment: That's good. Depending on the slope, I may consider re-grading as well. You want to be sure it can withstand the 'big storm'.

Comment: The slope is very slight. But for some reason there was never any gutters put up so all the runoff go into the garage as well. (which were doing the roof and gutters first.) Do you think the cinder blocks and concrete will work for the foundation in that area?

Comment: You don't really need a foundation (The footer is already there holding up the garage). You may put concrete there for aesthetic reasons (to tie into the rest) but note that concrete is in no way a water barrier. Just like any foundation, you really want to keep the water away from it in the first place so it doesn't have to act as a barrier.

Comment: Is the garage floor even with the rest of the house?  If so I agree with @DA01 and you have to regrade driveway.

Comment: There is no footer where the garage door is. There is one on each side. We will re grade the driveway.  But we need something in where the door was. That's why we're putting cinder blocks and cement. Just not sure on what kind of cement either.

Comment: Also thanks everyone for the ideas and tips and help.